# Is feature selection built into scikit-learn's SVMs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, feature-selection

I'm using SVMs to train a model using 1000s of features (X) and labeled data (y), with the intention of using it to make predictions of y_new. Some of the features will not be very important to predict y, so I want to reduce the number of features keeping the most important ones. On the [scikit-learn feature selection overview](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#l1-based-feature-selection), it is written:

> With SVMs and logistic-regression, the parameter C controls the
>   sparsity: the smaller C the fewer features selected.

Does that refer to SVCs (with all kernels) as well as LinearSVCs? In other words, if I want to use, say, SVC with the 'rbf' kernel, is it necessary to select a subset of features as a preliminary step (with [recursive feature elimination](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#recursive-feature-elimination), or [LASSO](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) for example) to find the most important features that I will then use to train my SVC, or can I train the 1000s of features directly with the SVC, and simply make C "small".

Comment: For LinearSVC if you select penalty='l1', the SVC will automatically select some of the features. No need to use some other method beforehand.